# Ballot file from 2nd 2011 Moderator Election causes decoding error

Tags: support, election

<sub>I suppose this is a technical question and may also be suitable for SO proper, but since it concerns the election I thought the target audience would be more likely to find it here.</sub>

When trying to run [the results](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/2) of our recent Stack Overflow Moderator Election <sub>[Armadillo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111270/should-that-be-2012-moderator-election/111283#comment288496_111283)</sub>, OpenSTV chokes with a `UnicodeDecodeError`. This makes determining the winners somewhat difficult. What gives?

Comment: FYI, the latest version of OpenSTV supports unicode.

Comment: Oooh vote fraud! Recount!  :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download link provided by SO is version 1.7 of OpenSTV.  This version does not support unicode but the latest version, 2.0, does.  The latest version is available from the OpenSTV.org website, and it costs $5.

Full disclosure, I run the OpenSTV project.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that OpenSTV is assuming that the ballot file is ASCII-encoded, but the chosen handle of one of the candidates, [NullUserException ఠ_ఠ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) contains some characters which aren't.

The quick fix is to simply remove the offending characters<sup>1</sup> from the ballot file. Change line 5014 from:

```
"NullUserException ‡∞†_‡∞†"
```

to:

```
"NullUserException"
```

<sub>Adding or modifying other lines, such as the actual votes, is possible, but sadly, will have no effect on the real world.</sub>

You will then be able to welcome our new ASCII-friendly <del>overlords</del> devoted volunteer stewards.

---

<sup>1</sup>By which I do *not* mean the candidate!

Comment: I am so glad I broke everything.

Comment: It's clear to me that this was a plot, hatched by you many many months ago, to destroy democracy by not allowing the votes to be tallied. I'm somewhat sorry to have foiled your plans; it was quite clever.

Comment: (Congrats, BTW!)

Comment: Did I earn a spot? That's impossible.

Comment: That's what my run of the results says.

Comment: This is extremely surprising. I was 6th in the primary phase, and I predicted I would *just* miss it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  Make sure you're calculating the result with the "Meek STV" method.

Comment: @Tim: Indeed I am. Looks like NullUserException collected a lot of transferred votes from other candidates who were eliminated.